# How to downgrade .NetStandard 1.6 to .NetStandard 1.3

Tags: .net

I try to use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. It requires .NetStandard1.3 to run.
But I only have NetStandard1.3 in my machine.

So How can I downgrade the version of .NetStandard to 1.3

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The hell is .NetStandard1.3?  Aaah, project.json settings, nvm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided, I would say you need to change the frameworks portion of your project.json and run `dotnet restore`

Change:

```
"frameworks": {
  ".NETStandard1.6": {}
}
```

To:

```
"frameworks": {
  ".NETStandard1.3": {}
}
```

Then, save and restore.

**Note**: `.NetStandard1.6`, `netstandard1.6`, and `netstandard16` are all valid values for the same thing.